# Rayleigh's Test for of Uniformity in R

Tags: r, statistics

I try to do a Rayleigh's test for circadian rhythm in R.

DEC_DAY_TIME is the decimal day time with 1.0 = 24 hours.

My data looks like that:

```
DEC_DAY_TIME CALC_ACTIVE
1  0.240972222     resting
2         0.25     resting
3  0.258333333     resting
4  0.259027778      active
5  0.259722222     resting
6  0.265277778     resting
```

These are the first 10 columns for example:

```
DEC_DAY_TIME<-c(0.240972222,0.25,0.258333333,0.259027778,0.259722222,0.265277778,0.265277778,0.265972222,0.268055556,0.270833333)
CALC_ACTIVE<-c("resting","resting","resting","active","resting","resting","active","active","active","resting")
```

I try to do it that way:

```
actres<-data.frame(CALC_ACTIVE,DEC_DAY_TIME)
rayleigh.test(x=actres,mu=circular(1))
```

But I get the error:

`Error in x%%(ang * pi) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Do I somehow have to calculate an angle or something? I couldn't find any examples in the internet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some data to show?

Comment: Of course, sry. I edited the question.

Comment: What library are you using for the `rayleigh.test()`? `cicular`?

Comment: I'd also like to know what version of R are you running and OS, none of the three packages for circular statistics that I have tried (`circular`, `CircStats` and `circlize` are available for my version 3.2.0)

Comment: I am running R 3.2.1 on Windows 7. Do you think it won't work on newer versions?

Comment: I still cannot use any of the packages, even after updating `R` to the latest version. Two suggestions. Reading the documentation, if you want to run the `rayleigh.test` as is, `x` has to be a vector. Therefore you should just run `rayleigh.test(DEC_DAY_TIME, mu=circular(1))`. You might need to transform your variable as it could be a half circle, instead of full circle

Comment: @erasmortg Hey, thanks for still trying to help! I can't understand why it isn't running at your R. So you were partly right about that x-vector. I answered below.

Comment: I am glad you got the test to work~ :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem:

I calculated the angle in degrees but default are radians.

There is another Rayleigh Test in the package CircStats with the parameter degree=TRUE

```
active.with.na<-DEGREES_DAY_TIME[CALC_ACTIVE=="active"]
active.without.na<-active.with.na[!is.na(active.with.na)] # remove NAs
r.test(x=active.without.na,degree=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
r.bar
[1] 0.4790981

$p.value
[1] 1.009254e-33
```